# how to redirect node/%node to custom page in drupal

Tags: drupal

I want redirect node/%node page of one content type to its related another content types node/%node page

Answer (score 5):

Using [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu_alter/6), alter the page callback for `node/%node`. In your page callback, check the type of the node to invoke `node_page_view` on the node or redirect to the referenced node.

```
MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node']['page callback'] = 'MODULE_node_page_view';
}

MODULE_node_page_view($node) {
  if ($node->type == MODULE_NODE_TYPE) {
    $referenced_node = MODULE_get_related_node($node);
    drupal_goto('node/'. $referenced_node->nid);
  }
  else {
    return node_page_view($node);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function to do a redirect is [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/6).

You can for example do that by implementing [`hook_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/6) in a custom module, check if the path is node/something, load the node and if it's type X, redirect.

Answer (score -1):

This could also possibly be done by putting `<?php drupal_goto($related_url); ?>` in a node-yourcontenttype.tpl.php in your theme folder.

Comment: This is just about theming, no redirection with that.

Comment: Template files are here to handle ... templates. They should not have any code that deal with the "life" of the site. A redirection is not a way to display some data.